# snowflake: mention date format staged data files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a tsv as below (just formatted for better repr) in a s4 bucket

```
col_1      | col_2 | col_3    
2017/12/01 | 1996  | 20101201 
..         | ..    | ..
```

All the above columns are of `DATE` type

I create a stage to load this file from s3

Now I have table created

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE 
    "test" 
    ( 
      col_1 Date,
      col_2 Date,
      col_3 Date
    );
```

Now i want to ingest the above csv into this table

```
-- create file_format
create or replace file format my_file_format
  type = csv
  field_delimiter = '|'
  skip_header = 1

-- create stage
CREATE or replace STAGE my_stage
URL='s3://xxxx/yyyy'
CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' AWS_SECRET_KEY='YYYYY');

-- copy into
copy into "TEST"
  from @my_stage
  file_format = (format_name = my_file_format);

-- or insert into
 insert INTO "test" (select $1,$2,$3 from @my_stage (file_format => my_file_format));
```

I get error

```
Can't parse '2017/12/01' as date with format 'AUTO'
```

I cant change the csv. Is there any way i can mention the date format for each col while ingesting.

Comment: Please update your question with the complete COPY INTO and FILE FORMAT statements you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use the proper date format based on the values?

```
 insert INTO "test" (select TO_DATE($1,'YYYY/MM/DD'),TO_DATE($2,'YYYY'),
 TO_DATE($3,'YYYYMMDD') from @my_stage (file_format => my_file_format));
```